# My Navigation Bar is blocked by a Javascript map. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I hover through my navbar it creates a dropdown menu but it gets blocked by the map, created with the script tag.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

```js
// JavaScript Document
//This will make the navigation bar responsive.
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1 {
 margin-top: 2.2em;
 margin-bottom: 2.2em;
 width:100%;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 5vmin;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.auto-style1{
 left: 25%;
 right: 25%;
}

#map {
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
}

.text{
 width:100%;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}

body {margin:0;}

/*This will style the navigation bar container*/
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 0;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  text-align:center;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/*This will style the items in navigation bar*/
ul.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
  display: block; 
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 13.75px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #F00;}

ul.topnav li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
}

/*This will style the dropdown container*/
ul.topnav .dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align:center;
    left: 0; 
}

/*This will style the dropdown items*/
ul.topnav .dropdown-content a{
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) { /* Allow responsive navigation bar */
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  ul.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content{
    width: auto;
    min-width: 160px;
    left: 0;
  }

  ul.topnav li.dropdown{
    position: static;
  }
}

.topnav li {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Footer CSS*/

body{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper{
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
}

footer{
    background-color:#333;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    align-self: flex-end;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

footer img{
    width:42px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

hr{
    width:100%;
}

footer p{white-space:pre;
font-size: 3vmin;} /* Change. Please apply to other footers. */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Contact Us</title>

<link href="_css/headfoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="_css/SPcontent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(http://hitcolors.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Green-1.jpg);
}
</style>

<script src="_script/headfoot.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">MENU</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Appetizer</a>
      <a href="#">Main Course</a>
      <a href="#">Dessert</a>
      <a href="#">Soup</a>
      <a href="#">Drinks</a>
      <a href="#">Side Snacks</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropbtn">PROMOTIONS</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="#">Breakfast</a> <a href="#">Lunch</a> <a href="#">Dinner</a> </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>
 <strong><b>Contact Us</b></strong>
</h1>

<div id="map" class="auto-style1">
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 3.9414186, lng: 108.3774456};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAgtkYIVZT6nPYk_xCl-2f50M3YWjNkUJM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <p>Address : 24,Jln Bunga Emas,43841 Syurga,Frankestain,Mars.</p>
    <p>Telephone Line : 03-87876666</p>
    <p>Email : 7Dwarfs@email.com</p>
</div>
    
<footer>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/icon-twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/YouTube-icon-full_color.png" alt="YouTube"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/original_instagram-circle-icon.png" alt="Instagram"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/tumblr-logo-icon-8.png" alt="Tumblr"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/google-plus-icon.png" alt="GooglePlus"/>
    <hr>
    <p>S   T   A   Y       C   O   N   N   E   C   T   E   D</p>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

What I wanna achieve is bringing the dropdown menu to the front and the bring the map to the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the perfect use case for **z-index**. To read more on it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index.

Essentially, the larger a z-index is, the "closer" to the screen it is than other elements with a smaller z-index. So in your case just set your navigation to `z-index: 2;` and the map to `z-index:1;`.